# Efficient way to write ordering instances?

Tags: sorting, haskell

I'm working on a basic Haskell exercise that is set up as follows: a data definition is made, where `Zero` is declared to be a `NaturalNumber`, and a series of numbers (printed out by name, so, for instance, `four`) up to `ten` is constructed with this.

I didn't have too much trouble with understanding how the declaration of `Eq` instances works (apart from not having been given an exact explanation for the syntax), but I'm having trouble with declaring all instances I need for `Ord` -- I need to be able to construct an ordering over the entire set of numbers, such that I'll get `True` if I input "ten > nine" or something.

Right now, I have this snippet of code. The first two lines should be correct, as I copied them (as I was supposed to) from the exercise itself.

```
instance Ord NaturalNumber where
    compare Zero Zero   = EQ
    compare Zero (S Zero)  = LT
    compare (S Zero) Zero  = GT
    compare x    (S x)  = LT
```

The first four lines work fine, but they can't deal with cases like "compare four five", and anything similar to what I typed in the last doesn't work even if I type in something like `compare four four = EQ`: I get a "conflicting definitions" error, presumably because the `x` appears twice. If I write something like `compare two one = GT` instead, I get a "pattern match(es) are overlapped" warning, but it works. However, I also get the result `GT` when I input `compare one two` into the actual Haskell platform, so clearly something isn't working. This happens even if I add `compare one two = LT` below that line.

So clearly I can't finish off this description of `Ord` instances by writing every instance I could possibly need, and even if I could, it would be incredibly inefficient to write out all 100 instances by hand.

Might anyone be able to provide me with a hint as to how I can resolve this problem and finish off the construction of an ordering mechanism?

Comment: Note: I'm a complete beginner to Haskell. It is possible I simply don't know the syntax well enough, particularly since I've generally found documentation for other languages I've used easier to read, but I feel like that's not the only problem here.

Comment: It looks like you'd like to use recursion in the last case, and have something like ```compare (S x) (S y) = compare x y```. Also you can use the underscore ```_``` to describe that you don't care about a detailed case, like ```compare (S _) Zero = …``` to note that you don't care for the size of the first number provided you know its >= 1 and the second is Zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What this task focuses on is finding base cases and recursion rules. The first two lines you were given were

```
instance Ord NaturalNumber where
    compare Zero Zero   = EQ
```

This is the first base case, in words:

> zero is equal to zero

The other two base cases are:

> zero is less than the successor of any `NaturalNumber`
>
> the successor of any `NaturalNumber` is greater than zero

Note that your lines three and four only say that `0 < 1` and `1 > 0`, but nothing about any other nonzero numbers.

The recursion rule, then, is that it makes no difference if you compare two nonzero numbers, or the numbers they are successors of:

> comparing `1 + x` and `1 + y` is the same as comparing `x` and `y`.

Codifying that into Haskell should give you the solution to this exercise.

Comment: This makes sense. I felt like recursion was supposed to be in there somewhere, (and now thinking about it, I have no idea why I replaced `compare Zero (S _)` with `compare Zero (S Zero)` at some point) but could not quite figure out how for some reason (bizarrely enough, despite something similar having shown up in the `Eq` instances).

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to organize your instances in a way that will cover all possible patterns. To make it simpler, remember how your numbers are defined:

```
one = S Zero
two = S one  -- or S (S Zero)
```

and think in terms of `S` and `Zero`, not `one`, `two` etc. (they are merely aliases). Once you do this, it should become clear that you're missing a case like:

```
compare (S x) (S y) = compare x y
```

Edit:
Like Jakob Runge noticed, also the following base clauses should be improved:

```
compare Zero (S Zero)  = LT
compare (S Zero) Zero  = GT
```

As they're written, they allow comparison only between zero and one. You should change them to cover comparison between zero and any positive number:

```
compare Zero (S _)  = LT
compare (S _) Zero  = GT
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `compare` function needs to be recursive.  You will want your last case to capture the situation where both arguments are the successor of something, and then recurse on what they are the successor of.  Additionally, your middle two cases, are probably not what you want, as they will only capture the following cases:

1. `1 > 0`
2. `0 < 1`

You would like this to be more general, so that you can handle cases like:

1. `S x > 0`, for all `x`
2. `0 < S x`, for all `x`

Comment: It also makes sense to use ```_``` for cases where the distance between both numbers is ```> 1``` .)

Comment: You probably meant `S _` instead of `S Zero` in the second and third branches.

Comment: For homework questions in particular, I don't think a code-only answer is appropriate.